# VBA:: Passing range results into an array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, for-loop

I am currently working on a search function in VBA that will take the results from a searched range and input the address of the cell location into an array.

I have attempted to set up the array with the following code.

```
Dim FindRange1 as Range
Dim Find1 as Range
Dim Results1() as Variant
Dim R1 as integer
Dim Max as integer

Max = Range("E7:E1000").Cells.Count

       Set FindRange1 = Worksheets("Properties").Range("P7:P1000")
            If ILsearch.P1B1.Value = True Then
                For R1 = 1 To Max
                    For Each Find1 In FindRange1
                        If (Find1.Value < TextBox1) And (Find1.Value > "0") Then
                            Results1(R1) = Find1.Address
                        End If
                    Next Find1
                Next R1
            End If
```

Comment: So what's the question?  What is it doing that you don't expect it to to?

Answer (score 2):

You need to dimension the array;

```
redim Results1(Max) '//this will leave an empty Results1(0)
```

Better to use a 0 index;

```
redim Results1(Max-1) 
...
Results1(R1 - 1) = Find1.Address
```

Note that this is creating an array with "gaps" where only indexes that meet your criteria are filled.

Comment: Even better to explicitly specify the lower bound: `ReDim Results1(1 To Max)` or `ReDim Results1(0 To Max-1)`. BTW I don't see why the latter would be better or worse than the former -- other than the latter inevitably leading you through a couple of debugging cycles because you forgot to write `- 1` a couple of places! Baaah, +1.

Comment: ya, i've set my code to be option base 1, so i feel 'code' ReDim Results1(1 To Max) 'code' suites my code better.  Thanks!